# Read-Host execution order

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do the following:

Display a list from a multidimensional array:

```
    $AssetList | Where-Object {$_.agenttype -eq "N"} | Select-Object number, hostname, agentstatus | Write-Output
```

Then read in a number from the user:

```
    $Victim = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the number of the host you want rid of...'
```

What happens in reality is the Read-Host is displayed before the Write-Output. How can I flip it and reverse it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Pause or Sleep after Select-Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835327/unable-to-pause-or-sleep-after-select-object)

Comment: My solution was to use `Out-String` instead of `Write-Output`. This solution doesn't seem to mention either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're using `Write-Output` (which writes to the output stream for your script/function). If you just want the data to be displayed on the console before the `Read-Host` cmdlet, try using `Out-String | Write-Host`. You can probably get away with just `Out-String` on its own.

> **Out-String**
>
> The Out-String cmdlet converts the objects that Windows PowerShell
>   manages into an array of strings. By default, Out-String accumulates
>   the strings and returns them as a single string, but you can use the
>   stream parameter to direct Out-String to return one string at a time.
>   This cmdlet lets you search and manipulate string output as you would
>   in traditional shells when object manipulation is less convenient.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849952.aspx

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Charlie.