# weird delay of the output of an object when followed by start-sleep (or until script end)

Tags: powershell, object, output, sleep

For some reason, the object won't output until the sleep command is done.

```
[pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'}; sleep 5
```

Here's another example.  You won't see the output until the loop finishes.

```
foreach ($i in 1..60) { 
  if ($i -eq 1) { [pscustomobject]@{message = $i} } 
  sleep 1
}
```

I guess you have to output at least 2 objects to see anything?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  After 15 seconds, you see both objects.

```
foreach ($i in 1..60) {
  if ($i -eq 1 -or $i -eq 15) { [pscustomobject]@{message = $i} }
  sleep 1
}
```

Or output enough properties (> 4) to implicitly call format-list instead of format-table.  *Format-table is the problem.*  This comes out right away.

```
[pscustomobject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4; e=5}; sleep 10
```

I wonder if a parameter to format-table could be added like `-NoWait`.

Known object types with format files containing column widths don't have this problem.

```
foreach ($i in 1..60) { 
  if ($i -eq 1) { get-process powershell } 
  sleep 1
}
```

Or objects that default to format-custom:

```
foreach ($i in 1..60) { 
  if ($i -eq 1) { get-date } 
  sleep 1
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to Pause or Sleep after Select-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835327/unable-to-pause-or-sleep-after-select-object)

Comment: @bacon I can sleep, I just can't see the output in a timely manner.

Comment: @js2010 The gist of that question isn't that `Pause`/`Sleep` aren't happening at all, but that they are happening _before_ a command that produces output despite being invoked _after_, which seems to be the same issue you're describing here.  There may have been better duplicates to suggest, but that question seemed to be the one to which many duplicates were linked.  Then again, I'm not sure I know what constitutes a potential duplicate on this site any more (if it's based on a common _question_ or mutually-applicable _answers_)...

Comment: @BACON, another near-duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375, and it links to the post you mention. The problem is that sometimes the _root cause_ may be the same, but the triggering scenarios and symptoms are sufficiently different and not obviously linked to the root cause so as to warrant specific explanations.  My personal M.O. is: address the specific scenario in an answer, but link to the near-duplicate that explains the root cause.

Comment: @js2010, I realized that the explanation in my answer wasn't quite correct, and I've updated it. In short: `Format-Table` can only detect whether the 300-millisecond delay has elapsed *if and when it regains control*, which happens only when the input command either _emits another output object_ or _terminates_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output less than 5 properties, and format-table implicitly runs.  Format-table will wait an *indefinite* amount of time for the second object, before displaying the first object.  This is for object types (like pscustomobject) without an xml file that define a *default* table view.

```
# no output for 5 seconds

&{get-date
sleep 5
get-date} | format-table


DisplayHint DateTime                               Date                 Day DayOfWeek DayOfYear Hour  Kind Millisecond Minute
----------- --------                               ----                 --- --------- --------- ----  ---- ----------- ------
   DateTime Saturday, February 8, 2020 10:24:48 AM 2/8/2020 12:00:00 AM   8  Saturday        39   10 Local         618     24
   DateTime Saturday, February 8, 2020 10:24:53 AM 2/8/2020 12:00:00 AM   8  Saturday        39   10 Local         892     24
```

Compare with format-list:

```
& {get-date
sleep 5
get-date} | format-list 

DisplayHint : DateTime
Date        : 2/8/2020 12:00:00 AM
Day         : 8
DayOfWeek   : Saturday
DayOfYear   : 39
Hour        : 20
Kind        : Local
Millisecond : 408
Minute      : 37
Month       : 2
Second      : 18
Ticks       : 637167910384087860
TimeOfDay   : 20:37:18.4087860
Year        : 2020
DateTime    : Saturday, February 8, 2020 8:37:18 PM

DisplayHint : DateTime
Date        : 2/8/2020 12:00:00 AM
Day         : 8
DayOfWeek   : Saturday
DayOfYear   : 39
Hour        : 20
Kind        : Local
Millisecond : 662
Minute      : 37
Month       : 2
Second      : 23
Ticks       : 637167910436622480
TimeOfDay   : 20:37:23.6622480
Year        : 2020
DateTime    : Saturday, February 8, 2020 8:37:23 PM
```

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**

- If a command's output is formatted with **[`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)** - whether ***implicitly*, as in your case**, or explicitly - ***display* output can *situationally* be *delayed*, for (at least) 300 milliseconds** (see next section for why and when), which has the following implications:

  - As in the question, **a *subsequent* `Start-Sleep` submitted *before* the delay has elapsed further delays output for (at least) the duration of the sleep**.

    - **`Format-Table` can only detect whether the 300-millisecond delay has elapsed *if and when it regains control***, which **happens only when the input command either *emits another output object* or *terminates*.**
  - With *implicitly* applied `Format-Table` formatting, a *subsequent* `Write-Host` or `Out-Host` call can produce output that unexpectedly comes *first*, as well as any call that targets an [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) *other* than the success output stream, e.g. a call to `Write-Warning` or `Write-Verbose`.
- You can *force* synchronous *display* output by piping the command to `Out-Host` or to `Format-Table` explicitly (or any of the other `Format-*` cmdlets); that is, the output order across the different streams is then preserved.

  - However, doing so means producing *for-display* output only, which means you lose the ability to (meaningfully) capture or relay the command's output.

```bash
# The Out-Host forces instant display, before sleeping starts.
# However, use of Out-Host means you can't capture the output.
[pscustomobject] @{message = 'hi'} | Out-Host; sleep 5
```

---

##### Background information:

The behavior is explained by the infamous [PSv5+ asynchronous behavior of implicitly applied `Format-Table` output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375): For data types *without predefined formatting data* that have *4 or fewer properties* (which is what auto-selects *table* display), it waits for up to 300 msecs. before displaying output, in an effort to determine suitable column widths.

If you use `Start-Sleep` before that period has elapsed, *output is delayed for (at least) the duration of the sleep*, because `Format-Table` doesn't regain control until it either *receives the input command's next output object* or the *input command terminates*.

Output objects that happen *not* to trigger implicit `Format-Table` formatting are not affected, however:

```bash
# Immediate output, before sleeping ends:

# Out-of-band formatting of a .NET primitive.
1; Start-Sleep 5

# Implicit Format-*List* formatting due to having 5+ properties.
[pscustomobject] @{ a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4; e=5 }; Start-Sleep 10
```

By contrast, because your command's output is an object with just *1* property and its type (`[pscustomobject]`) has no predefined formatting data associated with it, it triggers implicit `Format-Table` formatting and therefore exhibits the problem.

**In short: The following command outputs are affected**, because they select implicit `Format-Table` output while lacking predefined column widths, necessitating the delay:

- objects whose type happens to have ***4 or fewer* properties**
- *if* those types have ***no* associated predefined formatting data** (see [`about_Format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml)), which is generally true for `[pscustomobject]` instances.

  - Additionally, but far less commonly, types *with* formatting data that *default to table view* but don't have column *widths* predefined, are also affected (e.g., the [`System.Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Guid) type instances that `New-Guid` outputs).
  - As a - cumbersome - ad-hoc alternative to authoring formatting data, you can use `Format-Table` with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to *predefine a column width for every display property (column)*; however, note that this is again only suitable for *to-display* output; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Produces instant display output, due to predefined column widths.
    [pscustomobject] @{ a=1; b=2 } |
      Format-Table -Property @{ Expression='a'; Width = 10}, 
                             @{ Expression='b'; Width = 20} 
    Start-Sleep 5
    ```

Types *without* formatting data that have *5 or more properties* default to implicitly applied `Format-List`, where, due to line-by-line output, there's no need to determine useful column widths, and therefore no delay.

---

Note that this is **only a *display* problem**, and that if the command is captured or sent to a pipeline the data *is* immediately output (though the command won't finish overall until the `Start-Sleep` period has elapsed):

```bash
# The ForEach-Object command's script block receives the [pscustomobject]
# instance right away (and itself prints it *immediately* to the display, 
# due to outputting a *string* (which never triggers the asynchronous behavior).
& { [pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'}; sleep 5 } | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
```

---

While there are **several ways to *force* synchronous (immediate) display output**, they all ***change the fundamental behavior* of the command**:

```bash
# Piping to Out-Host:
# Directly prints to the *display* (host).
# No way for a caller to capture the result or for processing
# the result in a pipeline.
[pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'} | Out-Host; sleep 5

# Using Write-Host:
# Prints directly to the *display* (host) by default.
# While it *is* possible to capture the result via output stream 6.
# the information stream (6> file.txt), that output:
#  * is invariably converted to *strings*
#  * and the string representation does *not* use the friendly default
#    output formatting; instead, the objects are stringified with simple
#    [psobject.].ToString() calls, which results in a much less friendly
#    representation.
Write-Host ([pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'}); sleep 5

# Piping to a Format-* cmdlet explicitly:
# While this does write to the success-output stream (stream number 1),
# as the command would by default, what is written isn't the original
# objects, but *formatting instructions*, which are useless for further
# programmatic processing.
# However, for redirecting the output to a file with Out-File or >
# this makes no difference, because they convert the formatting instructions
# to the strings you would see on the screen by default.
# By contrast, using Set-Content or any other cmdlet that expects actual data
# would not work meaningfully.
[pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'} | Format-Table; sleep 5
```

Comment: To me, the current behavior doesn't make sense. It makes to sense to join multiple discrete statements into a single output. I raised an issue with the PowerShell team here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17392

Comment: I agree that it is problematic, @AxD: here are two older issues that are still open:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13985, the latter showing that the behavior can even result in data loss.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe your custom object to the `Out-Host` cmdlet:

```
[pscustomobject]@{message = 'hi'} | Out-Host; sleep 5
```

When you use the `Out-Host` cmdlet, you are immediately displaying the results to the host. Without it, the object is output to the pipeline which is not returned until after the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet.

Comment: _the object is output to the pipeline which is not returned until after the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet_ is only true _situationally_, and knowing _when_ it applies is what the OP's question is about. Also worth mentioning that using `Out-Host` means that the  command output prints straight to the display (host), and cannot be captured / redirected anymore.